# whenNew or expectNew are not calling real constructor while mocking

Tags: mocking, powermock, powermockito

I am mocking using all - powerMock / PowerMockito and whatever available out there to mock my constructor.

Here is the Class in which I am calling new constructor for Spring.

```
  public class BaseService {
        private void loadSpringConfig(String customResourceName) {
          String[] resources = new String[1];
          resources[0] = "test.xml";
          context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(resources);
        }
}
```

Here is the code I am using in mocking. Using wehnNew as well as expectNew is calling 'ClassPathXmlApplicationContext' constructor and giving file not found exception.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({BaseService.class, 
   ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.class})
public class BaseServiceTest {
    @Mock
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx;
    @Test
    public void loadSpringConfigTest() throws Exception{

        //ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = PowerMockito.mock(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.class);
        Method method;
        String[] resources = new String[1];
        resources[0]="test.xml";
        BaseService bs = new BaseService();
        try {
            method = BaseService.class.getDeclaredMethod("loadSpringConfig",String.class);
            method.setAccessible(true);
            //trowing exception of file not found - tried various option with no luck 
            PowerMockito.whenNew(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(ctx);
//Other tries
//withParameterTypes(String[].class).withArguments(resources).thenReturn(ctx);
            //PowerMock.expectNew(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.class,new Class[]{String[].class},resources).andReturn(ctx);
            method.invoke(bs,"test");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
}
```

Comment: Which version of PowerMock do you use ?

Comment: Hello Aurthur, I am using powermock-core-1.6.2

Comment: As for me everything looks fine, except that the method is called with using reflection. But it should not affect. I'll investigate.

Answer (score 0):

So much deep-diving into PowerMock dark powers ... when the answer could be so simple: **avoid** calling new.

Calling `new` in production code is (often, not always) the **wrong** thing today. It makes code much harder to test than it ought to be.

Thus:

- learn how to create easy-to-test code; for example by watching these [videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79)
- instead of calling `new`, use **dependency injection** and give your class a simple factory that it can use to acquire such a context.

No more `new`; and you can do all your testing with that kind of "black magic". Plus: the quality of your product improves as well.

Regarding the followup question - you already mock the object you want to inject?!

```
@Mock
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx;
```

creates a *mocked* ClassPath..Context object. You might want/have to configure that via when/then calls for example.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. but again, how to mock the injected objects?

Comment: This answer does not help people are in the 'not always' category of wrongness.

Comment: Who says that all answers must be helpful for 100 percent of all readers?